# check box getting checked based on the position of the if statement. js

Tags: javascript

On my onload (init()) function is acting weird. I have two if statements in my function, if i put checkbox with value 4 as first IF statement then that checkbox gets checked and viceversa (for checkbox with value 5). I have value of 5 in db but checkbox with value of 4 is being checked if i move second if statement as a first IF statement then everything works as normal. something is not right in my function can you guys please help me figure out. I will greatly appreciate for the help. I tried adding else if still having similar issues. Please suggest me so that my if statements do not override eachother

```js
function init(){//onload

if(document.getElementById('test').value == 4){
     document.getElementById('test').checked=true;
    document.getElementById('testing').checked=false;
     document.getElementById('testing').disabled =true;
     document.getElementById('test').disabled =false;
 }
 else if(document.getElementById('testing').value == 5){
 document.getElementById('testing').checked=true;
 document.getElementById('test').checked=false;
 document.getElementById('test').disabled =true;
 document.getElementById('testing').disabled =false;   
}

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="test" id="test">test
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="testing" id="testing">testing
```

Comment: Both `if` statements will evaluate to `true`, so both run, and the one that runs last will overwrite similar properties set by the one that ran earlier.

Comment: i tried adding else if , i am getting same result.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

1) We don't use "value" for checkbox type of input. Use ID or Name instead to identify them.

2) Below code is to show you when the 2nd checkbox is checked and it will disable the 1st checkbox.

```js
init()

function init(){//onload
console.log(document.getElementById('4').checked,document.getElementById('5').checked)
if(document.getElementById('4').checked == true){
    document.getElementById('5').checked=false;
     document.getElementById('5').disabled =true;
     document.getElementById('4').disabled =false;
 }
  if(document.getElementById('5').checked == true){
 document.getElementById('4').checked=false;
 document.getElementById('4').disabled =true;
 document.getElementById('5').disabled =false;   
}

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="4" id="test" >test
<input type="checkbox" id="5" id="testing"   checked="true">testing
```

3) Below code is to show you when the 1st checkbox is checked and it will disable the 2nd checkbox.

```js
init()

function init(){//onload
console.log(document.getElementById('4').checked,document.getElementById('5').checked)
if(document.getElementById('4').checked == true){
    document.getElementById('5').checked=false;
     document.getElementById('5').disabled =true;
     document.getElementById('4').disabled =false;
 }
  if(document.getElementById('5').checked == true){
 document.getElementById('4').checked=false;
 document.getElementById('4').disabled =true;
 document.getElementById('5').disabled =false;   
}

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="4" id="test"  checked="true">test
<input type="checkbox" id="5" id="testing" >testing
```

4) Both are the same code.